# Delete a child using RemoveChild()

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectnodes

My XML database:

```
<root>
  <car>
    <index>1</index>
    <brand>Ford</brand>
    <year>2006</year>
    <price>20000</price>
    <mileage>70000</mileage>
  </car>
</root>
```

Can someone show me how can I delete the whole record? (index, brand,year,price,mileage)
I know that I should use RemoveChild() but I can't do it.

```
doc.RemoveChild(doc.SelectSingleNode("//root/car/index[@='1']"));
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Why can't you do it? What error are you facing?

Comment: You should provide your c# code to make your question more clear. I don't downvote you but unclear question may get you in trouble with downvote

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post.
I added code.

Answer (score 2):

`RemoveChild` must be called on the immediate parent of the node to be removed, not on the document object. The node you're trying to remove is not a child of the document object; it is a child of the node `<root>`.

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//root/car/index[@='1']");
if(node != null)
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it